# R function to cbind the transpose of individual columns

Tags: r

I am looking for help on this topic but I think that the words I am searching for cannot provide me a solution.

I was looking for a function to go through a data frame and convert two rows into one row by going down each column and using this as the first part of the `cbind` function.

I originally have two rows of data but the only way I could think of doing this is combining them into a single data frame and creating a for loop to transpose each column and run `cbind` again.

What I have is this:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4
[1,] a1   a2   a3   a4
[2,] b1   b2   b3   b4
```

And I would like to have something like this, where if possible to attach an identifying prefix to the column name;

```
     a.col1 b.col1 a.col2 b.col2 a.col3 b.col3 a.col4 b.col4
[1,]  a1     b1     a2     b2     a3     b3     a4     b4
```

If anybody can tell me a useful package or function I would be very grateful!

Comment: `as.data.frame.list(c(as.matrix(df)))`

Comment: @akrun, I was thinking along the lines of `do.call(cbind, split(mydf, 1:nrow(mydf)))`...

Comment: Your input looks like it's a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
df$indx <- 1
res <- dcast(transform(melt(df, id.var='indx'), indx2=letters[1:2]), 
                          indx~indx2+variable, value.var='value')[-1]

res1 <-  res[order(sub('^.*_', '', names(res)))]
res1
# a_col1 b_col1 a_col2 b_col2 a_col3 b_col3 a_col4 b_col4
#1     a1     b1     a2     b2     a3     b3     a4     b4
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 gather(df, Var, Val, -indx) %>% 
                     mutate(indx2=rep(letters[1:2], length.out=n()))%>% 
                     unite(indx2Var, indx2,Var, sep=".") %>% 
                     spread(indx2Var, Val)
  #  indx a.col1 a.col2 a.col3 a.col4 b.col1 b.col2 b.col3 b.col4
  #1    1     a1     a2     a3     a4     b1     b2     b3     b4
```

Or

```
 as.data.frame.list(c(as.matrix(df)))
```

You can use `setNames` and `paste` to change the `column names`

```
 as.data.frame.list(setNames(c(as.matrix(df)),
         paste0(letters[1:2], '.', rep(paste0('col',1:4),each=2))))
 # a.col1 b.col1 a.col2 b.col2 a.col3 b.col3 a.col4 b.col4
 #1     a1     b1     a2     b2     a3     b3     a4     b4
```

Or

```
  df2 <- cbind(df[1,], df[2,])
  df2[order(colnames(df2))] #and change the column names
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("a1", "b1"), col2 = c("a2", "b2"),
  col3 = c("a3", "b3"), col4 = c("a4", "b4")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3", "col4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I actually need the resulting row to be `a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3 a4 b4` for any number of columns in the original data frame.

Comment: @jimmako The third option should give you in that order

Comment: @jimmako Or you can use `order` to change the order of columns. Please check the update

Comment: Yes this works for moving the data, thanks. But is it also possible to have a specific prefix equal to the original row name using the third option?

Comment: @jimmako It can be achieved with `paste` and `setNames`.